# Disable/Enable css comment line with gulp

Tags: css, node.js, npm, gulp, compass

Is there a way to disable a specific css comment at a certain line with Gulp, and enable it after a build task ?

For example, I would like to disable my @import 'compass/reset'; which is at the first line of my css file, and enable it after the build task.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. You need this [**Gulp plugin.**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-strip-code) It's called `gulp-strip-code` , you simply need to add two comment lines above and below it, just like the CSS/JS unifiers do, like so:

> **NOTE:** *I am writing this down, as I presume that you have the needed knowledge about Gulp.*

```
/* test-code */
@import 'compass/reset';
/* end-test-code */
```

It is fairly easy to implement. Just follow the instructions on the plugin page.

Navigate to your main project dir with the node folder and install it like so:

`npm install gulp-strip-code --save-dev`

Then, **[create a task for it](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/#article-header-id-5)** and pipe the custom comments that You would like to use like so:

```
.pipe(stripCode({
  start_comment: "start-test-block",
  end_comment: "end-test-block"
}))
```

Comment: It perfectly works ! Thank's a lot ! Do you know if there is a Gulp plugin which allow to add code ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your request here.. Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: Sorry... gulp-strip-code allow to strip some code. I would like, after strip my code, to add lines of code, to do the opposite of this Gulp plugin. Is that more clearer ? :)

Comment: I am sensing a disturbance in the force here. Are you trying something overly-complex that can be done in a simpler manner? Meaning - can't you just add the needed code manually or you are referring to something that is missing at the time of compiling a build?

Comment: You're right, it's a huge disturbance in the force ! I try to create a workflow with Compass AND Gulp. In my Gulp tasks, I try to minify my css files after my scss files are compiled. It perfectly works. But when I add some Compass Mixins, I get an error in my build tasks : File to import not found or unreadable: compass/reset. To do my goal working, I have first to do a Gulp Compass, and after comment my @import line for minify this file. I'm not sure if your understand what I'm talking about...

Comment: Are your Compass files installed globally trough some package manager or are they in your project directory as they should be?

Comment: This is my compass version when I write compass -v in my terminal directory : Compass 1.1.0.alpha.3

Comment: And these are my Gulp taks :

// "build"
gulp.task('build', ['compass', 'minify']);

// "watch"
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch(dossierSASS + '*.scss', ['build']);
});

// by default
gulp.task('default', ['build', 'watch']);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133900/discussion-between-sqnkov-and-pierre-meteye).